# If two matrices have the same eigenvalues, will they have the same characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This seems to hold, considering:

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2 &0\\0 &2\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$B=\left(\begin{matrix}2 &1\\0 &2\end{matrix}\right)$$

Is this always valid?

Comment: Do complex numbers count as eigenvalues in this context?

Comment: I suppose yes they do count.  @Omnomnomnom

Comment: More importantly, does multiplicity count? For instance, you could have characteristic polynomials $(x-1)^2(x+1)$ and $(x-1)(x+1)^2$. They have the same roots $1$ and $-1$, but not with the same multiplicity. This can't arise with a $2\times2$ matrix though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two matrices have the same polynomial exactly when they have the same eigenvalues, each with the same algebraic multiplicity.

Note that the characteristic polynomial is always a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ (or $(-1)^n$ if that's your definition), and that its zeros are precisely the eigenvalues of the matrix.  In particular, suppose that $A$ has eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$. The only polynomial with exactly these zeros is
$$
p(t) = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)
$$
so, this must be the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Note that the number of repetitions of an eigenvalue matters here.  In particular, a matrix with eigenvalues $\{0,0,1\}$ will have characteristic polynomial $t^2(t-1)$, while a matrix with eigenvalues $\{0,1,1\}$ will have characteristic polynomial $t(t-1)^2$.

Comment: Sine multiplicity hasn't been mentioned in the statemetnhere, i assume this staement is FALSE. Correct?

Comment: The problem is that "having the same eigenvalues" can mean $2$ things.  Depending on which one is meant, the statement is true or false.